# Media Query browser resizing issues

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm applying media queries on my project , but when I`m resizing the browser , it doesn't work.But when I resize it from the developer tool (inspect element) it works...It sounds ridiculous but I'll show you with images.

[image]

In the following picture. I've applied media query for my menu-bar. As you can see , when I resize my browser , it doesn't work.

[image]

but when I resize the project from the developer tool , it works... I've applied only `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` for the media queries.

The second issue is the following. Is there `<meta>` tag for tablets viewports?
Now my Media Query works on all mobiles , but on tablets doesn't. I've tried to reach some answer for mu issue but I didn't find anything...

Comment: You don't use another meta tag for different viewports, you create another media query. The standard is to design for the smallest size first (say 320px width) then work your way up making breakpoints using media queries where needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My thoughts are that its because your query only applies to the device. If you were to try something like:

```
 @media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    background-color:red;
 }
```

Try that, but to be honest, I would think about introducing a style framework like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com). 
It takes most of the headache around queries away. Also, it's great because you generally want to cater to mobile screens first, and Bootstrap does this pretty well by default.